# How do I get the N newest database entries using Eloquent?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I try to get the newest posts in a database. I tried this:

```php
$users = Post::take(10)->get();
```

This generates the 10 first posts in that model. I want the 10 newest. I have the table rows `created_at` and `updated_at`.

Comment: "Eloquent"..? What does that have to do with the question?

Comment: I updated for clarification, thanks!

Comment: Never even heard of eloquent, but a quick peek at the documentation shows `Post::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->take(10)->get();` should work?

Answer (score 0):

As Paolo Bergantino [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316663/using-eloquent-orm-how-do-i-get-the-n-newest-database-entries#comment26879364_18316663), this will do the job:

```php
# Get n latest posts #
$n = 10;
$latest_posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->take($n)->get();
```

For more information check the docs section: [Select - Order By, Group By, And Having](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#selects).

Comment: Although `created_at` may work on most cases, you should use `id DESC` if possible. It's a smaller field, faster to order and which, as a primary key, is always indexed. The only reason to use `created_at` is the absence of an auto incremented field.

Comment: Nice tip @vFragosop! I haven't realized this!

Comment: If the table has millions of posts, is this gonna be slow? Not using created_at though, using id